# Saving on a Model that has foreign and M2M relation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 3 models, say, Fruits, Season, and FruitSeason

```py
class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Season(models.Model):
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class FruitSeason(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fruit = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit)
```

I have a form that lets me add Season and (multiple)Fruit details

```py
class FruitSeasonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    season_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    fruit = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Add comma separated values'}))
    class Meta:
        model = FruitSeason
        exclude('fruit', 'season')
```

I tried saving the list of fruits as individual records in the Fruit Model as well as  season details in Season on Form post.

**views.py**

```py
class seasonal_fruit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FruitSeasonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        fruit_season_form = form.save(commit=False)

        season=Season.objects.create(season_name=form.cleaned_data['season_name'], country=form.cleaned_data['country'])

        fruit_season_form.save_m2m()
        form.save()
```

form post does not save on both the models.
FruitSeason model should have records for fruit IDs and Season IDs.
How do I work around with it? Not sure where am I going wrong. Is it the modelling of those 3 models or something else.

Comment: refer this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable naming is confusing and the order in which you do things is wrong:

```
if form.is_valid():
    fruit_season = form.save(commit=False)
    season = Season.objects.create(...)
    fruit_season.season = season  # assign the fk
    fruit_season.save()  # now save the instance
    form.save_m2m()  # do this on the form, not on the instance and after all objects are saved
```

But this would only work if `fruit` is defined as a m2m field on your form, which it is not since you replaced it with a comma-separated CharField. In your case, you need to create the `Fruit` objects manually and add them to the `fruit_season` instance manually.

```
if form.is_valid():
    fruits = []
    for fruit_str in form.cleaned_data['fruit'].split(","):
        fruit = Fruit.objects.create(name=fruit_str)
        fruits.append(fruit)
    fruit_season = form.save(commit=False)
    season = Season.objects.create(...)
    fruit_season.season = season
    fruit_season.save()
    fruit_season.fruit.set(fruits)
```